# Global JS variables not accessible from inside function

Tags: javascript

Sorry - I'm terrible at this and I've got a lot to learn.

I'm sure the answer is obvious to most here.

I declared email and password outside of any functions and set them to the value of their corresponding text boxes.

As soon as I'm inside the login() function the value doesn't carry inside.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const email = loginemail.value;
const password = loginpassword.value;
    
    function login() {
        alert(email);
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCodelogin = error.code;
            const errorMessagelogin = error.message;
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user;
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error2) => {
                const errorCoderegister = error2.code;
                const errorMessageregister = error2.message;
                pagebody.innerHTML = errorMessagelogin + "<br /><br />" + errorMessageregister;
            });
        });
    }
```

I have no clue what I'm doing

Comment: `const email = loginemail.value;` does not keep updating. it is the value at the time that code runs....

Comment: Your two global variables are getting their values immediately (probably before the user has had a chance to input anything) and those values are the ones that you use later in your function. Instead **declare** your variables globally and when you need their values (within your function), access their `value` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, got the login working!